# AJAX-based refresh without data duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I am confused about AJAX requests. I am using the `load()` function to refresh specific elements on the page. Unwanted duplication does not occur when there is only one matched element on the page.

```
{% for example in examples %}
<div class="refresh" id="single{{ example.id }}">
    <div class="container">
        <p> Different content </p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Assuming the above example, I would like to refresh the contents of a `container` with different contents in multiple elements on the page. In this case, if the 'examples' elements are four, there will be 8 after the refresh. I've tried everything I can find, but so far the data is duplicated.

**#1 UPDATE**
The script is placed in the `base` template, wrapped in `$(document).ready(function()`. AJAX of type `GET` on success the function `$( ".class-to-refresh" ).load(" .class-to-refresh")` is called.

PS The server displays a redundant request, but it does not duplicate data when there is only one item with the class `class-to-refresh` on the page. Otherwise, elements duplicate or overlap.

**#2 UPDATE**
Below I provide a simplified code containing the troubles ([online](http://tpcg.io/_EFKUML) version).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: location.href,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $( ".content" ).load(" .content" );
                    }
                });
            }, 3000)
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content" id="content1">
    Content
</div>

<div class="content" id="content2">
    Different content
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your `load()` function? How do you use AJAX?

Comment: Maybe you are calling the AJAX request twice?

Comment: I updated the topic. @Luke

Comment: @fbzyx Probably, but it is troublesome for many elements of a particular class.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you post complete code. Something that we could test in our own machine.

Comment: In your update you say that `load` called on success. This explains the duplicate request to your server. If you could include all of your related HTML, Python and JavaScript code it would help us understand your problem. Otherwise it is guessing and like solving a puzzle.

Comment: @fbzyx I added the code and a version to run online at tutorialspoint.

Comment: Possibly, look at the #2 update. @Luke

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The issue here is that you are doing your AJAX request twice.
First with `$.ajax(..)` and then with `().load()`.

You should only use one of the functions.

Maybe what you want to do should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function() {
                $( ".content" ).load("ajax/url/file.html .content" );
            }, 3000)
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content" id="content1">
    Content
</div>

<div class="content" id="content2">
    Different content
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

From the `load` documentation:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded.

Probably the code isnt perfect but you can read more about `.load()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/load/).

So in Django if you have this in your template:

```
{% for example in examples %}
<div class="refresh" id="single{{ example.id }}">
    <div class="container">
        <p> Different content </p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

then it will load all the existing example in examples and if you incert them with `.load()` you will have duplicated content.

Comment: I spent a lot of time, often all nights. I think I've already looked everything. I have partially corrected the data duplication. In truth, whether '$.ajax(..)' is with 'load()' or 'load()' is alone the result is the same. The first request is single, but each subsequent request is duplicated. PS I am also thinking whether to refresh the accordion body itself or all of them. If I refresh all on the page, the currently open accordions should not collapse. @fbzyx

Comment: maybe can you try changing  $( ".content" ).load(" .content" ); to something like  $( ".content-1" ).load(" .content-2" );. You have also two divs with the same class where you want to put the same content..

Comment: It took me a lot of time (and nights). I can say that it's a bit like divide and conquer, because I simplified the trouble to a minimum. 

I generally worked on something similar to what you say, but with a big difference. You wrote '$( ".content-1" ).load(" .content-2" );', but in this case one content would be loaded into the other. We are talking about something else.

Nevertheless, for the moment, let's focus on duplicating queries. Especially in the case of a looping (especially by your previous comment @fbzyx).